# Reference imported LESS styles but not output them

Tags: css, less

How can imported LESS styles be referenced but not outputted? I was sure that `reference` should do the trick but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

As [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvxLxL) shows,

```
.modal-content-custom {
  @import (less, reference) "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css";
  .modal-content;
}
```

compiles to

```
.modal-content-custom {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.modal-content-custom html {
...
```

So it just ignores `reference`.

Comment: what are the contents of `.modal-content`? Are they exactly the rendered output?

Comment: Yes. But it also adds every other css rule to the output (`.modal-content-custom html` illustrates it);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. `reference` import option is ignored for namespaced imports. This will work as expected.

```
@import (less, reference) "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css";

.modal-content-custom {
  .modal-content;
}
```